# Nodejs импорт большого XML

Tags: node.js, xml

Всем привет, пытаюсь импортировать большую базу товаров из XML, сам функционал я реализовал, у меня проблема в следующем:

Для старта импорта я сделал отдельный GET роут, импорт стартует нормально и продолжается какое то время, но через время просто прекращается, без ошибок и каких либо сообщений. С чем это может быть предположительно связано? Возможно есть какие то ограничения по времени выполнения в NODEJS?

Никаких критических нагрузок на сервер нет, база Mongodb, бекенд NESTJS, импорт идёт примерно на 2 тысячи товаров, а потом прекращается.

Сложность в том что никаких ошибок и вылетов нет, не знаю как это дебажить лучше. У меня мысли что есть какие то ограничения по времени выполнения

Comment: заканчивается timeout ожидания ответа от сервера, тут лучше аяксом подгружать частями

Comment: @ЕвгенийПлатов Слал запрос через POSTMAN, импорт продолжается и после превышения ожидания